# c++ conversion operators no candidate is better

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class test {
    private:
        std::string strValue;
        int value;

    public:
        test():value(0) { };
        test(int a):value(a) { };
        test(std::string a):strValue(a) { };
        ~test(){};

        operator int () { return value; }
        operator const char* () { return strValue.c_str(); }
};

int main() {
    test v1(100);
    cout << v1  << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the above, with gcc I get an error saying no candidate is better for conversion.. Aren't they exclusive types?

Comment: VC2010 compiles the code fine and chooses to execute `operator int`! I think you've just discovered a bug in VC2010!

Comment: You cannot expect the compiler to select which of the values you _mean_ to output, you must explicitly tell it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::ostream` has numerous `operator<<` overloads, including both of the following:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, int);
```

Your `test` class is convertible to both `const char*` and to `int`.  The compiler can't select which conversion to use because both conversions would work equally well.  Thus, the conversion is ambiguous.

Comment: To add to this answer, cast `v1` explicitly in the `cout` line to help the compiler out.

Comment: Yes, you could use a cast, but the better solution would be not to use conversion operators.

Answer (score 0):

test v1(100);
cout << v1  << endl;

Since cout doesn't have operator << (ostream&, test) it tries conversions. You provided two, both types are defined with ostream, so you got ambiguity.